# Firebase Android Query Not Returning Any Result

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase Database 9.0.2 for my app.

Database querying is working properly within the next few minutes after I perform a fresh install.
However, when I re-open the app after few minutes, both "**onDataChange**" and "**onCancelled**" method are not returning any result.
The query will work again if I reinstall the app or perform app data clear.

How I run the query:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("listings").child(id);
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //do something
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                //do something
            }
        });
```

Here's my database rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write" : true
    }
}
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: your code for querying the database ?

Comment: @Shubhank, updated with my querying code

Comment: in which function you call this >

Answer (score 2):

you might have used `addValueEventListener`, but it will be called when there is any change in that value.If you want to read data from database you need to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`.

```
mDatabase.child("users").child("childKey").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
    new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {



        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
```

refer [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#read_data_once) for more